# Following a TensorFlow tutorial - questions around IMG_SIZE and image size consistency

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence

I am following a [tutorial on TensorFlow image classifications](https://towardsdatascience.com/all-the-steps-to-build-your-first-image-classifier-with-code-cf244b015799).

In the first CreateData section of the tutorial it has a parameter:

```
# The size of the images that your neural network will use
IMG_SIZE = 50
```

I am wondering what this is? Is this a 50x50 pixel image? In my case I would like to train my model and allow my model to predict based upon differently sizes photos, they won't all have the same resolution or size. In this case, how will I alter the code within this tutorial to cater for that?

Also, in the bit of code used to run a prediction against a test bit of data, it also has the same `IMG_SIZE` param, so again the same question for this, in my use case, test data will be different sizes, so how can we cater for this?

Additionally, how many photos should I have for each of my trained classes at a minimum? Right now I have about 22 data points for each of my 3 cases, and the results are very poor, but that could equally be to do with the `IMG_SIZE` issue as above.

Any and all advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nothing to alter, they scale the image to that size with `cv2.resize`. Train and test images can be of different sizes. 22 images are too little unless you use some serious data augmentation and some pre-trained network

Comment: Great - is there a benefit to using IMG_SIZE of 100 then, instead of 50? Will it end with better results?

Additionally, how many photos should I be aiming for?

Comment: No one can say about that, there's a lot of experimentation involved..

Comment: Is there any guides discussing img_size scaling and the relationships to accuracy? Or even documentation for the parameter?

Comment: Not that I know of. Deep learning is more like alchemy than science at the moment :)